# On execution of following program I'm getting this error Line 11 if list[mid]<n: IndentationError: expected an indented block

Tags: indentation

pos = -1

def search(list, n):

```
l = 0
u = len(list)-1

while l <= u:
    mid = (l+u) // 2

    if list[mid] == n:
        globals()['pos'] = mid
        return True
    else:
        if list[mid] < n:
            l = mid+1;
        else:
            u = mid-1;

return False
```

list = [4,7,8,12,45,99,102,702,10987,56666]
n = 10

if search(list, n):
print("Found at ",pos+1)
else:
print("Not Found")

Answer (score 0):

It works fine, i think you have a different white space in line number 11. Try to update white spaces. You should only have tabs or spaces, you should not mix them.